# How does ear training help me find the key of a song?

Tags: intervals, ear-training, relative-pitch

I want to understand how ear training to identify different intervals helps me figure out what notes are in a song, and what key it's in.

Comment: I think you mean _ear training_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with a purely. or nearly purely diatonic song, yes, it will be of use. But not just on its own.

Knowing major and minor thirds will identify which sort of key a song is in. Providing one can find places where the song feels at rest, places where it could finish, leaving one with that 'ah, we're home again' feeling.

Knowing what a leading note is likely to do, and aware that it's a semitone from the root, will help identify a key when there's a perfect cadence. As will knowing what a P4 sounds like, in the same circumstance.

There aren't *that* many intervals to get your head round, and generally, if you understand the main ones, your playing will improve, initially thinking along the lines of 'the next note is a P5 from where I am now, so it'll be...there, on this instrument.' And this mindset becomes automatic eventually.

I use it in lessons. Play a short (initially) phrase, in a specified key, and the student will map it out in their mind, and play it back, without much trouble.